# PutDatabaseRecord is too slow with SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, apache-nifi, mssql-jdbc

I'm new using NiFi and I'm using **PutDatabaseRecord** processor to load data in Avro Format into **SQL Server**.

My data flow is something like this:

**EXECUTE SQL > UPDATE RECORD > PUT DATABASE RECORD**

But the write speed its too slow (800 rows/s).

In an other environment using MySQL I improved it using some options in jdbc connector (useServerPrepStmts=false&rewriteBatchedStatements=true), but in SQL Server there is no options like these.

**Is there another way to improve write to SQL SERVER ?**

Thank you,

Comment: Give it a try with `PutSQL` processor by setting `Concurrent Tasks = 2` and `Run Duration = 2s`, also try tweaking these properties with different values to check whether  you are getting desired result.

Comment: Hey Vikramsinh! Thank you! I tried to use PutSQL increasing the Concurrent Tasks=2 and greater values,  Run Duration=2s and it really increased the write (~1500 rows/s). But I still think it's slow when compared to other tools (for example: Pentaho DI that writes ~8300 rows/s when enable 'batch insert').

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the Concurrent Tasks on the PutDatabaseRecord and make sure your DBCPConnectionPool & database are configured to allow enough concurrent connections

Comment: Thank you Sdairs! I increased Concurrent Tasks (2,4,6,8) and it improved writes to ~1550 rows/s however deadlocks errors was increased too. In an other legacy tool (Pentaho DI) we have a option to enable 'batch inserts' and it really improve the write performance. Is There an option like this in Nifi?

Comment: They should already be batched, there is a config option to control the maximum batch size - try playing with that option and see if it makes any difference. https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.13.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutDatabaseRecord/

Comment: @LucasViniciusTeodoro Some additional info would help also - can you update your question with version of nifi & screenshot of your flow